# Archivos Python

Tags: python

```
csv1
123 Agustin Lopez 80000
154 Martin Avila 80000
201 Lucia Amado 60000
266 Gabriela Bueno 90000

csv2
130 Alejandra Milo 70000 A
153 B
154 90000 M

Salida
123 Agustin Lopez 80000
130 Alejandra Milo 70000
154 Martin Avila 90000
201 Lucia Amado 60000
266 Gabriela Bueno 90000
```

Son dos archivos con nro de legajo, nombre y sueldo el cvs2 tiene un campo mas de tipo alta, baja modificacion, pero cuando tengo el csv2 sin todos los campos completos me sale un error en,

```
legajo_nov, nombre_nov, sueldo_nov, tipo = leerNov(archivo2)
ValueError:not enought values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

Paso el código .

```
def leerMae(archivo):
        linea = archivo.readline()
        linea = linea.rstrip('\n')
        if linea:
            return linea.split(',')
        else:
            return "","",""

def leerNov(archivo):
    linea = archivo.readline()
    linea = linea.rstrip('\n')
    if linea:
        return linea.split(',')
    else:
        return "","","",""
    
def grabar_MaeActualizado(f, leg, nom, sueldo):
    f.write(leg + ',' + nom + ',' + sueldo + '\n')

def grabar_error(f, leg ,nom, sueldo, tipo):
    f.write(leg + ',' + nom + ',' + sueldo + ',' + tipo + '\n')


arMaestro = open ("maestro.csv","r")
arNovedades = open ("novedades.csv","r")
arMaeActualizado = open("maestro_actualizado.csv","w")
arLogErrores = open("logErrores.txt","w")


legajo_mae, nombre_mae, sueldo_mae = leerMae(arMaestro)
legajo_nov, nombre_nov, sueldo_nov, tipo = leerNov(arNovedades)
```

En este código es cuando viene el cvs2 con los campos ordenados y completos, cuando quise hacerlo con los campos como en el ejemplo que pase desordenados e incompletos, no me salia.

Comment: Bienvenida Julieta, te sugiero que agregues el código que estaría generando el error, aunque viendo los archivos es fácil intuir que el problema está en el archivo 2, hay filas que tienen 4 columnas (que es lo que estás esperando) y otras con dos, que son las que generan el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué necesitas? ¿Ignorar las filas incompletas?. De lo contrario, si solo necesitas crear un nuevo archivo, de la suma de los dos anteriores y ordenado por la primera columna, entonces no debería importar si está incompleta o no la línea.

Comment: Si en el csv2 tengo una A (alta)lo copio igual, si es una B(baja), va a un archivo de error, y si es una M(modificado) modifico el sueldo y copio legajo, nombre y sueldo  modificado.

Comment: Modifica tu función `leerNov` para que siempre retorne una tupla con cuatro valores, incluso si la línea del csv sólo tiene 2 (puedes rellenar los otros dos con `None` por ejemplo). Si no es esto lo que necesitas, deberías dar más detalles de qué querrías hacer en esos casos en que las lineas no tienen cuatro campos.

Comment: def leerNov(archivo):
    linea = archivo.readline()
    linea = linea.rstrip('\n')
    if linea:
        return linea.split(',')
    else:
        return "","","",""  , esta es la función @abulafia como tendría que editarla par que retorne una tupla con cuatro valores, también tengo el caso que pueden venir 3 valores y según esos valores pasar los datos actualizados.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene de que tu función `leerNov()` no siempre retorna 4 elementos (si la línea del fichero tiene menos campos, retornará sólo los que haya).

Puedes usar la siguiente estrategia para forzar a que siempre retorne cuatro. Troceas la línea que has leído, y retornas los trozos que hayas obtenido, **más** tantas cadenas vacías como sean necesaria para completar 4 elementos.

Esto puedes hacerlo con una línea:

```
def leerNov(archivo): 
   trozos = archivo.readline().rstrip('\n').split(",")
   return trozos + ['']*(4-len(trozos))
```

Por cierto que esta estrategia funciona también para líneas vacías, pues en ese caso el resultado de `split(",")` será una lista con un solo elemento, la cadena vacía `['']`. Mi función completaría esa lista con otras tres cadenas vacías más. Así que no necesitas verificar antes `if linea`.

Comment: Hola @abulafia provee  pero no me funciono, me sale un error de  too many value to unpack (expected 4)...como puedo pasar mi código, intente editar la pregunta, pero no me deja publicarla.

Comment: Si no muestras el código y el error es difícil adivinar qué puede estar pasando. Si el error te aparece en la línea `legajo_nov, nombre_nov, sueldo_nov, tipo = leerNov(arNovedades)`, y la función `leerNov()` es la que dí en mi respuesta, eso indicaría que alguna línea tiene **más** de cuatro campos, lo que podría suceder si en ella hubiera más de tres comas.

Comment: Funciono, era un error  mío, pero quería comentarte, cuando actualizo los datos, quedan completos todos los campos, pero además tengo otro archivo de errores, como ser baja de un legajo que no existe....y me queda así:      ##  253,B, ,  # #201,B, , ## 266,KatarinaFerro,95 000,A  ## 286,6000,M,  ##hay alguna forma de sacar las comas.

Comment: Pues claro! Si las comas esas las estás poniendo tú, en la función `grabar_error()`. Basta que no las pongas ahí, o que las cambies por espacios o lo que necesites ¿no? O te estoy entendiendo mal?